# How to store temporary data that has no logged in users

Tags: facebook, api, laravel

I am working on an app using Laravel that retrieves posts from facebook pages (using fb IPA) then make some operations on them, this tool can be used with no login or creating an account, and my question is: 
how and to store the temporary data I get from the API since I don't have users knowing this app can be used by many people at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could solve this in several ways. I'm not quite sure what you do the get the data.

You'll need something unique to relate to the data. In case you login to the API using OAuth you could request the user profile of the user ([example here using the Facebook SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/howto/example_retrieve_user_profile)) and grab the user id or the email address. In case you do not login then you could use something like the session id.

Comment: I mean using the app don't need a login from the user, obviously the app will have authorisation to use the API, what I mean where and how should I store that temporary data I get from the API since I have no logged in users to the app?

Comment: Well you have multiple options here. You could just save it to a database using something unique (see answer above) to relate to it or you could just save it to the session of the visitor. It really depends on your use case which for me is still quite vague.

Comment: Your answer mainly was about the API side and that not an issue for me, my concern is storing data temporarily, my question is not vague but general, I wanted to know in what are the different ways to do that, but thanks anyway

Comment: I did not mean that your question was vague, just meant that what you plan to do with the data was a bit vague for me. This is the reason I can not fully recommend saving it to a database or to just use the session to store the data cause this would really depend on what you plan to do with the data. In case you want to count how many records you've retrieved or do a sum of a specific field later on it would would be easier to use a database.